# How to get HTTP id from angular and send it to java?

Tags: java, angular

I have this code in Angular, and I need to get this simboxid and to send it to java endpoint.

mno.components.ts
    ngOnInit() {

```
this.mList.getMnosList().then(data=>this.mnos = data);
}
```

mno.service.ts

```
  getMnosList() {
    var simboxid = this.getItem.id;
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/MNO` +  ['simboxid'] )
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => <mno[]> res)
                .then(data => { 

                  return data;
      });
```

mno.ts

```
 export interface mno{
     id;
     name;}
```

In java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MNO")

public class MNOList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    int simbox_id;
    public int getSimbox_id() {
        return simbox_id;
    }
    public void setSimbox_id(int simbox_id) {
        this.simbox_id = simbox_id;
    }
    String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Java endpoint:

```
@Path("/MNO")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
public class MnoListPoint {



    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    @GET
    public String get(@QueryParam("simboxid") String id) {
        return JsonbBuilder.create().toJson(em.createNamedQuery("Select m from MnoList where simbox_id = :simboxid").setParameter("simboxid", id).getResultList());
    }

}
```

Help me to understand how to get this simbox_id when I click on specific simbox.

[Here is the id that I need because this 2 tables simbox and Mno are connected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w77Eg.png)

Comment: You just append `['simboxid']` to the path, but you need to add something like `"simboxid=?" + simboxid`

Comment: I was trying with  let simboxid = 1;
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/MNO`+ simboxid) ,   but this only give the apiUrl   /MNO1

Comment: @LoginConnecter, because you are not sending it correctly to service: You should use: `return this.http.get(${environment.apiUrl}/MNO?simboxid=${simboxid}) `

Comment: This is an example of primeng use: https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `mno.service.ts` service:

```
getMnosList() {
    var simboxid = this.getItem.id;
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/MNO?simboxid=${simboxid}` )
            .pipe(map(this.extractData)),
                   this.catchError);
```

Or use `HttpParams` to send the query params:'

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

getMnosList() {
        var simboxid = this.getItem.id;
 let params = new HttpParams().set('simboxid', simboxid);
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/MNO`, { params: params } )
 .pipe(map(this.extractData)),
                       this.catchError);

private extractData(res: any): any {
        return res.data || []; // or do what needs to be done
    }

private catchError = (observable: Observable<any>): Observable<never> => {
        return <Observable<never>>observable.pipe(catchError((error: any) => {
            return observableThrowError(error || 'Server error');
        }));
    }
```

In your component just subscribe to service:

```
this.mList.getMnosList().subscribe(data => { this.mnos = data })
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this.getItem.id is correct, I'm getting this error, ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @LoginConnecter, that means you do not have `getItem` defined (as code shown in your question has it) or the item doesn't have a property id. The best is to send the itemId to service method  EX: `getMnosList(id)` and use it for creating httpParams.

Comment: and what should I add here this.mList.getMnosList(id).then(data=>this.mnos = data 
  ????);

Comment: @LoginConnecter, depending on your response, it could be just `this.mnos = data ; `  or `this.mnos = data.data` And it should not be then.. The Best way is to add a subscription in component: `this.mList.getMnosList().subscribe(data => { this.mnos = data })`

Comment: it is not working with subscribe, I build this table  from here ->  https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table   
 ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars = cars);
    }

Comment: what version of angular do you use? Can you share a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gk2ls3
For subscribe to work you need your service method to return an Observable not a Promise. Please check my updated answer

Comment: Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15

Comment: Check this for an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6